# procedure entry point not found when running from cmd/explorer but running fine in eclipse cpp

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I just wrote a simple program that edits a file in C++.
After freshly installing Eclipse and MinGW following the guides on the net, everything seemed to be working fine. The program compiles and runs perfectly within the eclipse command window hook.

[Screenshot of the program running fine in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEpC2.png)

When I try to start the program out of my cmd window or just out of the explorer, I get an error message about the procedure entry point not being found.

[Screenshot of the error message (in German)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnLkZ.png)

This says something like:

"The Procedure Entry Point (...) was not found in the dll (...) PdftexFixer.exe."

I tried different compile options, all work fine within eclipse but the problem persists.

The program does not utilize any custom dlls. I tried cleaning the project foulder and compiling again from scratch. MinGW paths are set in the systems environment variables.

Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: can you translate the error message ?

Comment: i added the translation in an edit.